# panoramagl hotspot to move to next panorama

Tags: java, android, xml

here is the code of panoramagl in which cylinderical panorama is working with hotspot but how to go to next panorama by clicking on it here is my code in which hotspot is clickable but not move to next panorama can anybody help me

```
PLManager plManager;
PLHotspot hotspot;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    plManager = new PLManager(this);
    plManager.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    plManager.onCreate();

    PLCylindricalPanorama panorama = new PLCylindricalPanorama();
    panorama.getCamera().lookAt(0.0f, 200.0f);
    panorama.getCamera().setPitchRange(-30.0f, 30.0f);
    panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.z), false));
    plManager.setPanorama(panorama);
    panorama.addHotspot(new PLHotspot(1, new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.hotspot), false), -10.0f, 180.0f, 1.05f, 1.05f));


    hotspot.getOnClick();


}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to override following method

```
@Override
            public void onDidClickHotspot(PLIView view, PLIHotspot hotspot, CGPoint screenPoint,
                    PLPosition scene3DPoint) {

                 Toast.makeText(view.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 String.format("You select the hotspot with ID %d",
                 hotspot.getIdentifier()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but its too late (2 months of delay)

Comment: If you want fast responses, hire a developer and pay for his/her work. Free responses from community come when possible :-) Employers need more culture. Tell this to yours

Comment: culture is always welcome bro. Even 10 years late. Let the software industry have culture, don't worry about dates ;-) btw I told this to Muhammad